# Two Command in Button Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I would like two put these two command in one button. I use for loop, to generate grid buttons.

```
PC=Button(pc_area, text='RESERVE').pack()
PC['command'] = lambda PC=PC:reserve_confirmation(PC)
PC['command'] = lambda x=line: func(x)
```

Comment: PC is `None` as `pack()` returns `None`. So instantiate `Button` in one line and then pack it in another. To call multiple event handlers use `Button(root, command=lambda :fun1() or fun2())`

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it works.

```
PC['command'] = lambda PC=PC,x=line:[reserve_confirmation(PC),func(x)]
```

Comment: Or you can define commands during declaration of button itself. Also question should be asked within posts and not in a answers.